# Django: m2m select with thumbnails

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django development and trying to build my own site with a portfolio of my work and a blog.

The portfolio part of my site has posts that include a variable number of images to use as thumbnails.

In Django admin, I would like to be able to see thumbnails of each image in the select form.  Django's filter_horizontal is very close to what I am looking for, but it can't display thumbnails of the images

Anyway, the models involved look something like this:

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    original = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    medium = ...
    thumbnail = ...

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, blank=True)
    description = RichTextField(max_length=1000)
    content = RichTextField()
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS60H.jpg) is a mockup of what I am trying to achieve.

I've been reading through the documentation on Forms, ModelForms, and Widgets, but I am not entirely sure how to piece it all together or if I'm looking at the wrong thing entirely.  Any help would be much appreciated, even if it's just pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel I'd recommend you to use a third-party app like [sorl-thumbnail](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io) or [easy-thumbnails](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.io).

Comment: Unfortunately, those, on their own, only seem to be able to get me the thumbnail after I have selected the image.  I am trying to see the image before I select it.  I know I can open a new tab, search my images, and use the image id, but I want something a little more seamless.

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time to come up with this as well. The problem is, that it is hard to grab the widget. my solution consists of two parts.

First i change the **str** representation of the related ImageModel to return the image_url

```
class ArticleImage(ImportModel, ImageModel):
    image = models.ImageField(help_text='Artikelbild')
                           related_name='images', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url
```

Then I overwrite my admin form **init** method to return the url (here you can filter as well, if you dont want to show all images that you have saved)

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ArticleRelatedImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    images = []

    article_related_images = ArticleImage.objects.all()

    for image in article_related_images:
        images.append(
            (image.pk, mark_safe('%s' % image.image.url))
        )

    self.fields['images'].choices = images
```

finally the magic happens in my base.html. I copy the file from External Libraries/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html and add my own jQuery Magic at the bottom of the file:

```
<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
jQuery('.related-widget-wrapper').bind("DOMNodeInserted", function () {
    jQuery('#id_images_from option').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).attr('style', 'background: url(' + jQuery(this).text() + '); height:100px; width:200px; ' +
            'background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain; margin: 5px; background-position: center;' +
            'color:rgba(0,0,0,0);');
    });
    jQuery('#id_images_to option').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).attr('style', 'background: url(' + jQuery(this).text() + '); height:100px; width:200px; ' +
            'background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain; margin: 5px; background-position: center;' +
            'color:rgba(0,0,0,0);');
    });
});
```

As soon as filter horizontal gets loaded, the select list 'id_images gets changed to id_images_from and id_images_to. This method detects when this is happening, and renders the thumbnails. It also detects when a image gets selected or unselected or new images get added.

This only gives you the thumbnail centered in the list, without a title. I made the title invisible with the color attribute, but I think this could be a start for you.

This solution is for sure not flawless, as I am a beginner, but I hope it still helps you a little. For me it works fine.

Cheers, Codebeat.